# Compiling Clapack for find_package ( LAPACK

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, lapack

I have to use Clapack as a replacement for blas/lapack in an environment without Fortran compiler. However, some subprojects use find_package ( LAPACK to detect lapack which always fails. Only find_package ( CLAPACK would work.

My question now is would it be possible to compile CLAPACK in a way that it will be detected by find_package ( LAPACK calls?

Regards

Comment: I am not sure doing it this way is the best way to go. What I would do is try to find LAPACK. If lapack is not found try to Find CLAPACK. You can then setup some cmake variables for your libraries and header file so the rest of the project can use either transparently. This way you can even add some defines for conditional compilation if one or the other is present.

Comment: Problem is there are a lot of occurences in subreps and I don't want to create own branches for everything especially not what is maintained by other people.

Comment: No Fortran compiler? Suggest : Install a local compiler (gccXx, g++Xx, gfortranXx) if you have no permissions to install a system version. Debian example `gcc85-c++_8.5.0-8LOCAL_amd64.tar.xz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bBpgh_fmULC_OQkuc4Y6eD85rg2ZSzzI/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yeah that is plan B but it involves a lot of politics.

Comment: Maybe you can just provide a FindLapack.cmake in the path that find CLapack instead of Lapack ? That one might be a good base to work from: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/clapack/FindLAPACK.cmake